# How to get phone number from address book as string?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a text field with a contact name and I want to get the phone number for that:

```
ABAddressBookRef adressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSArray *people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(adressBook,
                               CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                 (CFStringRef)recipient));

if((people != nil) && ([people count] == 1)){
    ABMultiValueRef person = (ABMultiValueRef)[people objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, 
                                                      kABPersonPhoneProperty) ;
    NSLog(@"%@", phone);
}
```

I want the phone number as string but this gives me a lot more:

```
ABMultiValueRef 0x339470 with 1 value(s)
    0: _$!<Mobile>!$_ (0x338c50) - 0177 1647788 (0x339450)
```

How to I get just the number as string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty);
for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);++i) {
    CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
    NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) phoneNumberRef;

    [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
}
```

Comment: thanks that helped, but why I need to loop over it since I have just one contact? you example gives me ( 1222... ) with that round brackets, how to get the string without the brackets?

Comment: One contact can have multiple numbers, the numbers will be stored in the array 'phoneNumbers'. To get the first: [phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:0]

Answer (score 2):

kABPersonPhoneProperty is a multi-value property, but you're treating it as a string. You should get the individual numbers and print them separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
CFStringRef phoneRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty) ;
NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) phoneRef;
```

Comment: thanks, but you code still gives me the same result as in my question, I want just the number

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for phone extraction. You can extract the phone numbers from a text and then replace it with @"", for example:

```
NSString *userBody = @"This is a text with 30612312232 my phone";
if (userBody != nil) {
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:userBody options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [userBody length])];
    if (matches != nil) {
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
            if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {
                DbgLog(@"Found phone number %@", [match phoneNumber]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`